# ViewData and HtmlHelper.Partial riddle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I try to figure out htmlhelper's viewdata and viewcontext behaviours. Here's the case:

**MainView.cshtml:**

```
@{ViewBag.Title = "add excercise";}

<h2>title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Edit(p => p.Name)
    @Html.Edit(p => p.BodyParts)

    <button>Send</button>
}
```

**My own Edit extension method:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString Edit<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
     var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
     html.ViewContext.ViewData.Add("Metadata", metadata);
     html.ViewData.Add("Metadata", metadata);

     var mvcString = html.Partial("MultiSelect", html.ViewData);

     html.ViewContext.ViewData.Remove("Metadata");
     html.ViewData.Remove("Metadata");

     return mvcString;
}
```

**Mvc HtmlHelper's Partial extension method from PartialExtensions.cs:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString Partial(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName)
{
     return Partial(htmlHelper, partialViewName, null /* model */, htmlHelper.ViewData);
}
```

My idea is to decorate `Html.EditorFor` method, so I call my own **Edit** method, where I create metadata for currently processed viewmodel's property and then pass this metadata object to partial view, where I eventualy call `Html.Editor` for decorated property.

Now's the riddle - in my own **Edit** method both `Html.ViewData` and `Html.ViewContext.ViewData` don't contain `Title` data which was set in MainView and both contain newly added metadata object.

However in HtmlHelper's Partial extension method there is completely different situation - htmlHelper's ViewData doesn't contain metadata set up be me one step earlier, but contains `Title` property set up in MainView (which wasn't present in `ViewData` step earlier). Moreover `htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData` does contain my metadata object and doesn't contain Title from MainView as was one step earlier.

My question is - how did this happen? I didn't see any decorators on `ViewData` property, or `HtmlHelper` and whole `ViewData` object was changed in one instruction - i.e. calling Partial extension method, not even yet executing this partial view.

My aim is to pass metadata object with all `ViewData` to partial view, but as a result I either have metadata or `Title` (title is just example - it can be some much more important properties).